# github committed files don't show up on

Tags: github, push

Newb question:

I add a file to my repo (drag it to my repo folder) then in git bash I "cd" to my repo and "git init", "git add filename", "git commit -m 'committing files'". When I git status it says

```
$ git status
#on branch master
#your branch is ahead of origin master by 2 commits
#
working directory clean. Nothing to commit.
```

But they don't show up in my repo when I refresh the page on my github site. Do I have to push them to the site?

Answer (score 7):

> Do I have to push them to the site?

Yes. Commits are to your local repository first. You need to `git push origin master` for the commits to be on GitHub.

Comment: okay. That is what I thought but I questioned it because when I try to do that I get the message that I need to enter my key. Then it gives me the famous public access denied error. I looked at other forums and made sure my .ssh file exists and such but still no luck. Can I reset the pass phrase for the key they are asking for?

Comment: Okay. So reseting and making a new password worked. ssh-keygen

Answer (score 3):

You need to push the changes out to your remote on github.

You've commited the changes to your local repository - but that doesn't automatically push them out to your remote. Try this:

```
git push origin master
```